# Does anyone else experience an 'h2o malware' issue?

Tags: h2o

I ceased using h2o a few yeas back when I discovered a malware issue.

After obtaining a new Mac, I decided to give it another shot and install h2o.  The problem still persists.  I use VirusBarrier Scanner and rarely experience any inflected files of any type.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with H2O, it is a known vulnerability with much older versions of Java: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2012-0507

Comment: Thanks TheFon.  With the Java/CVE-201200507 file quarantined, I downloaded and installed the current version of Java from java.com (version 8 333). I then attempted another initialization of h2o.  It indicated it was performing a one time install of h2o.jar as it did this morning before the malware was detected and quarantined.  I immediately scanned the downloaded version of h2o.jar, and I received the exact same malware quarantine notification again.  Thoughts?

Comment: I tried scanning the last release and I was able to reproduce the issue. We do not believe there is any malware in the h2o.jar and we expect this to be a false alarm. We do have security scans on our products and this vulnerability was never flagged, also the description of the vulnerability doesn't match what the content of the jar has.

Comment: H2O bundles this library that is being flagged by the antivirus software: org.threeten:threetenbp:1.5.2 - this library is safe and doesn't present any risk to the users. We will be reporting the issue to the makers of VirusBarrier here: https://www.intego.com/support/submit-malware

Comment: Thank you, Michal.  That's peace of mind.